# Android reverse geocoding can I obtain a county name for areas in Great Britain

Tags: android, geocoding, google-maps-api-2, reverse-geocoding

I am playing around learning Java to build apps. I have came across a rather large flaw in the reverse geocoding from Google. I am creating an app to simply display a users town, county, country etc form their location.
I can retrieve various things by using:

```
list = geoCoder.getFromLocation(lat, lng, 1);
                        Address address = list.get(0);
                        // sending back first address line and locality
                        result = address.getLocality() + ", " + address.getSubAdminArea() + " , " + address.getPostalCode()  + " , " + address.getCountryCode();
```

This works well as you can see but the getAdminArea and getSubAdminArea works well for lat/lng points in america but is there a way of retrieving something similar for Tyne and Wear or County Durham in Great Britain?